# Line of Sight Check Theta* Algorithm

Tags: path-finding, navmesh, graph

I am looking at implementing the Theta* algorithm in a 2D NavMesh.
I have A* working, and I need to add a line of sight check to turn it into Theta*, this seems relatively easy in a uniform grid but a bit trickier in a NavMesh. There is excellent documentation on the funnel algorithm [here](https://digestingduck.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-stupid-funnel-algorithm.html), however this seems better suited to A* post smoothing.

Is there an method that would be better suited to Theta* line of sight checks in a Navmesh, or would I just need to use a modified version of the funnel algorithm?

Comment: http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/theta-star-any-angle-paths/ Link to Theta*

Comment: It's not clear to me how you can use the funnel algorithm to compute `LineOfSight(s1,s2)`. Conceptually you want to follow the line from `s1` to `s2`, determining which edges get crossed. I'm assuming all your polygons are convex, so the line intersects the boundary of each polygon at most twice. If you enter a polygon at one of those points, you can just find the other point and proceed to the next polygon.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of specificity, I am using triangles as polygons. I suppose it would be more accurate to say that the concept of the funnel algorithm could be applied to work with Theta* . If you have a line going from Point A to Point B and want to check if Point A can go straight to point C, create a funnel for the area in the Path A-B-C, create portals between A and C, and check that the line AC goes through all portals

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually you want to follow the line from `s1` to `s2`, determining which edges get crossed. The details depend on your representation of the NavMesh, but let's suppose it consists of triangles and allows the following operations:

```
# Returns the three vertices of the given triangle in CCW order
GetVertices(t)
# Returns the three triangles adjacent to this one.
# Ordered so that GetAdjacentTriangles(t)[i] shares entries i and i+1 of GetVertices(t).
# An entry may be None if the edge is on the boundary of the navmesh.
GetAdjacentTriangles(t)
```

Suppose we already know the triangles `t1`, `t2` containing `s1` and `s2`. Then the following <s>Python</s> pseudocode determines whether there is a line of sight:

```
def LineOfSight(s1,t1,s2,t2):
  d = s2 - s1 # Direction from s1 to s2
  n = (-d.y, d.x) # Normal to line s1-s2.
  ns = Dot(n, s1)
  while t1 != t2:
    dp = [Dot(n, v) for v in navmesh.GetVertices(t1)]
    for i in xrange(3):
      if dp[i] < 0 and dp[(i+1)%3] >= 0: break
    # We should cross the edge between vertices i and i+1.
    t1 = navmesh.GetAdjacentTriangles(t1)[i]
    if t1 is None: return False # We stepped off the NavMesh
  return True
```

This can probably be improved; it computes the same dot product multiple times, and probably mishandles the case where the line from `s1` to `s2` coincides with an edge in the NavMesh.